# Match text from two different lines using Regex

Tags: redex

Hei.

I have an accounting system called Adra Matcher and I want to use it to match two different lines containing some of the same text in both lines. An example of the text is "INV 7895852", but the numbers will always be different from pair to pair.
The two lines with the same 11 characters (INV -------) should match.

This is examples of one type of text:

20220830 USD 792 CHQ# 4545 INV 8888828

20220830 USD 1440 CHQ# 4585 INV 8924216

20220830 USD 1152 CHQ# 2584 INV 8812578

20220830 USD 324 CHQ# 66088287 INV 8945308

Those lines are to be match with these lines:

20220830 Public Schools INV 888828

20220830 COLLEGE INV 8924216

20220830 School District INV 8812578 check

20220830 School District CHQ 1584255 INV 8945308 check

The only thing that for sure is the same in the two lines are INV and the 7 digit after.

Can someone help me with this code?

Maren

Tried these different codes, but some didnt work at all, and one matched lines that didn't have the same number in the text.

Comment: Please provide a small sample (like, 4 lines) with mock data, and the desired result.

Comment: I also suggest you to use this website https://regex101.com/ to test your pattern against regexp